# '800a0e78' - object closed - worked previously

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I've searched high and low to resolve this one, but can't seem to fix it on my own. I'm new to classic ASP but a very long time PhP dev.

I'm getting

> > ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
> >     Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
> >     /sdd/fx_mlogin.asp, line 54

While logging in to the site i'm working on. The line's that's its referencing is:

```
Set rs = cmd.Execute
If RS.BOF or RS.EOF then
```

More relevant code:

```
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open MM_ap_connect_STRING
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "sd_member_login " & "'" & guid & "', " & """" & trim(user) & """, " & "'" & trim(pw) & "', " & "'" & uip & "', " & "'" & uagent & "', " & "'" & logintrack & "'"
Set rs = cmd.Execute
If rs.BOF or rs.EOF then
```

The kicker is that the site worked before and we're moving hosts. The connection is apparently working, but I'm suspicious that its still the issue. My connection string is

```
MM_ap_connect_STRING =  "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data source=sql2103.shared-servers.com,1087;Initial catalog=database;User Id=username;Password=password;"
```

But obviously with the username, password, and database fields filled in. I'm also connecting to a SQL 2005 database. Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: Is the connection associated with the cmd object opened? Is the chunk of code you're showing above embedded in some sort of conditional looping structure such that the connection is not being closed before the Execute fires?

Comment: Its not within any looping structure or condition, it just seems to be closing automatically.

Comment: The code before is

`Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open MM_ap_connect_STRING
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "sd_member_login " & "'" & guid & "', " & """" & trim(user) & """, " & "'" & trim(pw)  & "', " & "'" & uip & "', " & "'" & uagent & "', " & "'" & logintrack & "'" 

Set rs = cmd.Execute`

and then the next line is the error line:

`If rs.BOF or rs.EOF then`

Comment: You might consider setting the command type to StoredProc, although I doubt that's what's wrong. Since you moved hosts, are you sure you still have clean connectivity back to the database?

Comment: I've got connectivity, but I think I just found where the code is breaking. I think the the cmd i'm executing is broken from IIS 6 to 7.5. I have no idea why, but the cmd string that is closing the rs is `cmd.CommandText = "sd_member_login " & "'" & guid & "', " & """" & trim(user) & """, " & "'" & trim(pw)  & "', " & "'" & uip & "', " & "'" & uagent & "', " & "'" & logintrack & "'" `. I checked all of the variables, and they all contain data. Not sure why its breaking now when it didn't before though

Comment: please just edit the question adding code to comments is unreadable

Comment: Since you rehosted, have you verified permissions on the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the T-SQL line:

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON
```

to the top of the SQL being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue. For me the answer was my stored procedure had an owner of DBO. Which my user for the previous database was set to DBO. On our destination database there was a different DBO, which caused a execute permissions issue. Just changed my db user to DBO and it's working now. Hope that helps.